# Create DC/OS app deployment from native executable local file

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

I'm experimenting with DC/OS I would like to try out the native file running capabilities, run an native executable without using docker, outlined at https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/tutorials/dcos-101/app2/

I can successfully follow the tutorial but I would like to use my own application (a self-contained executable), the online documentation says that the fetch command supports the file:// uri in addition to the https:// uri and others. (https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/application-basics.html)

So if I use the app deployment manifest from the tutorial as my basis, but I've uploaded my executable to my master node at /home/core/app (in the linux filesystem)
and change the uri to "file:///home/core/app" the deployment says

> I0127 14:42:06.533756 40159 fetcher.cpp:167] Copying resource with command:cp '/home/core/app' '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/a0ff5689-5816-4812-864b-b3c4b914a272-S0/frameworks/a0ff5689-5816-4812-864b-b3c4b914a272-0000/executors/dcos-101_app2.c641de8d-e49e-11e6-93c4-de7054394bed/runs/f266a00c-1179-48bb-9f1e-251f3eae1272/app'
>   cp: cannot stat '/home/core/app': No such file or directory"

Using DC/OS 1.8 installed on CoreOS with one master and one agent (just for dev test)

I'm sure I'm just missing something fundamental like the mesos filesystem, but I've looked everywhere for a tutorial and they either assume your using docker, or serving via http...nothing for file://

So when using the file:// uri is that a different location than the linux filesystem or am I missing something else.

Little help please for a DC/OS newb

Thanks

EDIT

Here is the app.json file

```
{
  "id": "/dcos-101/app2",
  "cmd": "chmod u+x app && ./app",
  "args": null,
  "user": null,
  "env": null,
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 128,
  "disk": 0,
  "gpus": 0,
  "executor": null,
  "constraints": null,
  "fetch": [
    {
      "uri": "file:///home/core/app"
    }
  ],
  "storeUrls": null,
  "backoffSeconds": 1,
  "backoffFactor": 1.15,
  "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 3600,
  "container": null,
  "healthChecks": null,
  "readinessChecks": null,
  "dependencies": null,
  "upgradeStrategy": {
    "minimumHealthCapacity": 1,
    "maximumOverCapacity": 1
  },
  "acceptedResourceRoles": null,
  "ipAddress": null,
  "residency": null,
  "secrets": null,
  "taskKillGracePeriodSeconds": null,
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "port": 10000,
      "labels": {
        "VIP_0": "/dcos-101/app2:10000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "labels": {
    "HAPROXY_GROUP": "external"
  },
  "requirePorts": false
}
```

Comment: Please provide your Marathon app spec, that is, the JSON file that defines how you launch the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work, unless `/home/core/app` exists on *each* of your Agent nodes or you change it to, say, an external HTTP URL. What `fetch` does is: it downloads the listed file(s) into the Mesos sandbox, depending on the URI schema in use. Since you're using the `file:` schema, Mesos tries to download it on the Agent where the task is launched (and not the Master).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it by placing the file on my agent and that was successful. I had assumed that fetch retrieved the file off the master you were connected to and then placed it in the sandbox of the node it was deploying to. That would make better sense to me. But this solution will work for quick dev stuff, so I don't have to setup a http repo. Thanks for your prompt help!